# Return Value Based on Conditional Lookup on Different Pandas DataFrame

Tags: sql, python-3.x, pandas, lookup-tables

Objective: to lookup value from one data frame (conditionally) and place the results in a different dataframe with a new column name

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'user_id': [1,2,1,4,5],
                    'name': ['abc','def','ghi','abc','abc'],
                    'rank': [6,7,8,9,10]})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame ({'user_id': [1,2,3,4,5]})

df_1 # original data

df_2 # new dataframe
```

In this general example, I am trying to create a new column named "priority_rank" and only fill "priority_rank" based on the conditional lookup against df_1, namely the following:

- user_id must match between df_1 and df_2
- I am interested in only df_1['name'] == 'abc' all else should be blank

df_2 should end up looking like this:

```
|user_id|priority_rank|
     1     6
     2     
     3
     4     9
     5     10
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this:

```
In []:
df_2['priority_rank'] = np.where((df_1.name=='abc') & (df_1.user_id==df_2.user_id), df_1['rank'], '')
df_2

Out[]:
   user_id priority_rank
0        1             6
1        2              
2        3              
3        4             9
4        5            10
```

Note: In your example `df_1.name=='abc'` is a sufficient condition because all values for `user_id` are identical when `df_1.name=='abc'`. I'm assuming this is not always going to be the case.

Answer (score 3):

Using `merge`

```
df_2.merge(df_1.loc[df_1.name=='abc',:],how='left').drop('name',1)
Out[932]: 
   user_id  rank
0        1   6.0
1        2   NaN
2        3   NaN
3        4   9.0
4        5  10.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `map`:

```
df_2.assign(priority_rank=df_2['user_id'].map(
    df_1.query("name == 'abc'").set_index('user_id')['rank']))

   user_id  priority_rank
0        1            6.0
1        2            NaN
2        3            NaN
3        4            9.0
4        5           10.0
```